# React/redux app renders blank screen on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I built an app in React/redux that works in every browser I tried, BUT Safari on MacOS and any browser on iPhone. I get no error, no console message, nothing that would give me some idea. It only renders  tag in Safari and the screen is blank.

http://podcast.exploration.io

Do you have any idea how could I trace this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing console.logs all over the place, to see if you can spot a point of failure in Safari? That would be a good first step.

Comment: Yeah, I did. The action is logged in the action reducer. Then there is redux saga that should pick up that action and do some async job...that never gets called though. I was wondering how would I go about figuring out what happened in such cases

Comment: If your reducers are receiving the actions, but redux-saga is not, that makes me guess that there's an issue with your middleware being applied. Are you  using any store enhancers that may not work with Safari, like the Chrome DevTools Extension or something?

Comment: This is how I create the store:
`const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))`
besides that I don't do any other store enhancements. To keep the store state, I'm using immutable. Would sharing a source with you help?

Comment: Could it be problem of webpack? Maybe it'd help if I showed the build config for webpack

Comment: did you find any solution ?  same thing happening with me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue. The main reason why it failed was 'fetch' function...which is not available in Safari. I'm not sure why it wouldn't print anything, but I suspect, because 'fetch' was called inside try/catch.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to how you solved it?

Comment: Long time ago, but I guess some fetch polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. my list items would get rendered but not painted. so I could see them in dev tools, but they were all white/transparent.
I tried adding a `transform: translateZ(0)` to the list items, and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a blank screen on one device but not another, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61215326/470749

Also, this could happen if your code uses `fetch` somewhere, and your browser doesn't support it.

Check for browser and OS support: https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch

### The [official Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#note-on-fetch) say:

> We use `fetch` API in the examples. It is a new API for making network
>   requests that replaces `XMLHttpRequest` for most common needs. Because
>   most browsers don't yet support it natively, we suggest that you use
>   `cross-fetch` library:
>
> ```
> // Do this in every file where you use `fetch` 
> import fetch from 'cross-fetch'
> ```
>
> Internally, it uses `whatwg-fetch` polyfill on the client,
>   and `node-fetch` on the server, so you won't need to change API calls if
>   you change your app to be universal.
>
> Be aware that any `fetch` polyfill assumes a Promise polyfill is already
>   present. The easiest way to ensure you have a Promise polyfill is to
>   enable Babel's ES6 polyfill in your entry point before any other code
>   runs:
>
> ```
> // Do this once before any other code in your app 
> import 'babel-polyfill'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem. It was due to the use of lookbehind in a regular expression, which does not seem to be supported by Safari. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group)

Comment: I think it is caused by one of the Javascript dependencies that needs an update. For more detail, use developer tools to check chunk files to see which dependency is causing the issue.

Comment: @Lucas David this was really helpful this is exactly my case. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fetch for me too.
As I'musing webpack I add to correctly import i following this article: http://mts.io/2015/04/08/webpack-shims-polyfills/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I come to realize that I had to update the version of `antd` and `@ant-design/charts` and it worked well.